# Pasar datos de controlador a una vista C# Asp.net MVC 5

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

Hola buenas tengo un problema al pasar los datos que recibo en el controlador a la vista cree una vista del tipo detail especificando mi modelo pero al momento de intentar obtener la vista esta no se muestra tengo una tabla de noticias la cual tiene los datos de id nombre descripcion y detalle en mi pagina home muestro la imagen y el nombre de la noticia lo que intento hacer es redireccionar a mi vista detalle pasando el nombre la imagen y el detalle de la noticia  pero no se reciben los datos en el detalle

mi controlador **NoticiasController.cs**

```
public ActionResult VerDetalle(int? Id)
        {

            DBEntities db = new DBEntities();
            Noticias obj = db.Noticias.Find(Id);
            return View(obj);
        }
```

la vista de noticias **Noticias.cshtml** (las noticias las listo desde un json utilizando un script)

```
<div class="col-4 mb-4">
            <div class="card" style="width: 20rem;height:32rem">
                <img class="card-img-top" width="40px" height="215px" src="${objn.Imagen}" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">${objn.Titulo}</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">${objn.Descripcion}</p>
                    <div class=" position-absolute fixed-bottom mb-2 d-flex justify-content-center">
                   <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="verdetalle(${objn.Id})">Leer Mas...</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

script **ver detalle.js**(con este script paso el id de la noticia al controlador talvez no es la mejor manera de enviar el id pero quiero centrarme en pasas el detalle de la noticia a la vistaDetalle)

```
function verdetalle(Id) {
    var obj = noticias.find(x => x.Id == Id);   
        $.post("/Noticias/VerDetalle", obj, function (resp) {
        });
}
```

como dato adicional estoy utilizando un modelo para realizar las operaciones de listar editar y eliminar las noticias no cuento con un modelo para el detalle la vista pasa el id directamente al controlador ademas de aclarar que ya recupero el id en el obj de la noticia desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: ¿Qué hay en network? ¿Puros null? ¿Error 404?

Comment: hola no me aparece ningun error el problema es que no conozco la forma de pasar esos datos a la vista y talvez este coetiendo un error en la logica

Comment: Creo que esto te vendría bien: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykY un mega resumen de 4 horas que fueron 27 horas aprox de un curso que llevé en lo que fue la Microsoft Virtual Academy. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Hola Logre solucionar mi problema y espero sea de utilidad para alguien que quiera realizar algo similar lo primero que realice es descartar el onclick de ver detalle

```
onclick="verdetalle(${objn.Id})"

function verdetalle(Id) {
    var obj = noticias.find(x => x.Id == Id);   
        $.post("/Noticias/VerDetalle", obj, function (resp) {
        });
}
```

y en su lugar utilizar un href de esta forma href="/Noticias/VerDetalle/Id"
por ultimo cambiar la etiqueta `<button></button>` por `<a></a>` ya que segun encontre en el foro en ingles [aqui la pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35816007/bootstrap-button-href-does-not-work) que realizo otro usuario los button almenos el de bootstrap a lo que entendi no reciben el atributo href ya habia probado cambiar el evento onclick por  el href= " " pero no habia investigado sobre el error en el boton solamente con esos cambios logre mostrar el detalle de la noticia y por ultimo agradecer a @fredyfx por las pautas en su video